# Can't find php error log, can I set it on runtime to record errors in a different file?

Tags: php, error-handling

So I'm coding php on a friends site and the hosting provider has hid the php error log somewhere we haven't been able to find. It would be very useful in debugging the code, is there some code I can add to the top of the script to record the errors in a file I pick?

Edit: I've tried Dagon's suggestion with a test file with the following code:

```
ini_set("log_errors","1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("error_log", "/actual_file_path/Errors.txt");
print_r(file_get_contents("/actual_file_path/Errors.txt"));
fake_function();
```

The file path is correct because `print_r(file_get_contents("/actual_file_path/Errors.txt"));` is printing the text I added to the file. When the page dies form calling `fake_function()` nothing is recorded in Errors.txt. Really strange.

Comment: who is the hosting provider?

Comment: @RonakPatel Direct Admin